# Regex issue with named captured pairs

Tags: php, regex

I have the following value:

```
start=2011-03-10T13:00:00Z;end=2011-03-30T13:00:00Z;scheme=W3C-DTF
```

I use the following regular expression to strip out the 'start' and 'end' dates and assign them to their own named capture pair:

```
#^start=(?P<publishDate>.+);end=(?P<expirationDate>.+);#ix'
```

Probably not the absolute best REGEX, but it works well enough if both 'start' and 'end' values are present.

**Now, what I need to do is still match 'publishDate' if 'expirationDate' is missing and vise-versa.**

How can I do this using a single expression? I'm not the greatest at regular expressions and I'm starting to wander off into the more advanced stuff, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Mr. Chung, I have resolved this issue with the following expression:

```
 #^(start=(?P<publishDate>.*?);)?(end=(?P<expirationDate>.*?);)?#xi
```

As always, thank you so much for all of your help, everyone. :)

Comment: Considered splitting to two regexs?

Comment: I have, but, unfortunately, due to the constraints within the system I cannot do this without additional development; just not an option right now. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use (...)? for an optional section

```
^(start=(?P<publishDate>.+);)?(end=(?P<expirationDate>.+));)?
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought. I guess I was placing the parenthesis in the wrong points. There was a missing one in your example, but it gave me enough guidance to resolve the issue. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

These both set the named buffer to a value (instead of null or undefined)
I recommend the first one.

**1.** To find either/both in any order:
`/^(?=.*\bstart=(?P<publishDate>.*?);|(?P<publishDate>))(?=.*\bend=(?P<expirationDate>.*?);|(?P<expirationDate>))/ix`

```
/^(?=                                 # from beginning, look ahead for start
       .*\b                               # any character 0 or more times (backtrack to match 'start')
       start=(?P<publishDate>.*?);        # put start date in publish 
    |  (?P<publishDate>)                # OR, put empty string publish 
  )
  (?=                                 # from beginning, look ahead for end
       .*\b                               # same criteria as above ...
       end=(?P<expirationDate>.*?);
    |  (?P<expirationDate>)
  )
/ix
```

**2.** To find either/both in start/end order:
`/^(?:.*\bstart=(?P<publishDate>.*?);|(?P<publishDate>))(?:.*\bend=(?P<expirationDate>.*?);|(?P<expirationDate>))/ix`

**Edit -**

@Josh Davis -  I had to go searching PCRE.org, some great stuff there.

With Perl there is no problem with duplicate names.
Docs: "If multiple groups have the same name then it refers to the leftmost defined group in the current match."
The is never a problem when used in an alternation.

With PCRE ..
Duplicate names will work properly with PHP if its used with the branch reset.
Branch reset insures duplicate names will occupy the same capture group.
After that, using the dup names constant, $match['name'] will either contain a value
or an empty string, but it will exist.

ie:

(?J) = PCRE_DUPNAMES
(?| ... | ...) = Branch reset

This works:
`/(?Ji)^

 (?= (?| .* end = (?P<expirationDate> .*? ); | (?P<expirationDate>)) )

 (?= (?| .* start = (?P<publishDate> .*? ); | (?P<publishDate>)) )

/x`

Try it here: http://www.ideone.com/zYd24

```
<?php 
$string = "start=2011-03-(start)10T13:00:00Z;end=2011-03-(end)30T13:00:00Z;scheme=W3C-DTF"; 
preg_match('/(?Ji)^
      (?= (?| .* end = (?P<expirationDate> .*? ); | (?P<expirationDate>)) )
      (?= (?| .* start = (?P<publishDate> .*? ); | (?P<publishDate>)) )
    /x', $string, $matches);
echo "Published = ",$matches['publishDate'],"\n";
echo "Expires   = ",$matches['expirationDate'],"\n"; 
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output

```
Published = 2011-03-(start)10T13:00:00Z
Expires   = 2011-03-(end)30T13:00:00Z
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [expirationDate] => 2011-03-(end)30T13:00:00Z
    [1] => 2011-03-(end)30T13:00:00Z
    [publishDate] => 2011-03-(start)10T13:00:00Z
    [2] => 2011-03-(start)10T13:00:00Z
)
```

Comment: I think that duplicates named subpatterns are disallowed by default, have you tried your regexp in PHP?

Comment: I confirm that this regexp won't work in PHP. I think it's possible to enable PCRE_DUPNAMES by using the internal option `(?J)` at the beginning of the regexp, but I didn't test it fully.

Comment: @Josh Davis, I researched, it does work using (?J), but it has to be used right and that means using branch reset with it (?|). Its very valuable if used correctly. A working php version is in my edit. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

If **'start=;'** isn't present when the corresponding date is absent, the  Stephen Chung's code is OK

Otherwise I think that replacing '+' with '*' is enough:

```
#^start=(?P<publishDate>.*?);end=(?P<expirationDate>.*?);#ix'
```

By the way, the **'?'** is necessary to make the point ungreedy in every code