# Regex in .NET: joining duplicate named captured groups

Tags: .net, regex

Given the expression    `^(?<res>a).*(?<res>c)` and test string `abc`, expected named group `res` to concat both found values and get `ac`, but got latest change - `c`.

Any way for C#'s regex class to support concat for named groups within regex?

Related question is [Regex issue with named captured pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290065/regex-issue-with-named-captured-pairs/5290765#5290765), and by the chance it says that Perl/PCRE does not supports duplicate named pairs, but here I got .NET, and looking for it's specific magic to make regex return a *single* match that contains both found values from different parts of string (that is, abbbbbcdef should return ac).

Calling regex more than once or joining resulting groups in code is not a well-tolerated solution now - looking to do the whole job inside regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Current solution is to assign group names in ascending order for each condition: `((?<group0>))|((?<group1>)(?<group0>))`

After matching, all found groups are put to list and sorted by their name, building a final query string from either `group0,group1` or just `group0` (depending on what condition was matched).

Another trick is the need to start matching from beginning:

`^(?wastebytes(condition)(chance1)|(chance2))`

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of non-unique group names is merely to provide more flexibility in capturing parts of the string.  Taking the captured parts and reassembling them differently is something you do *after* the regex has matched--typically with the `Replace` method:

```
string s0 = @"abbbbbcdef";
string s1 = Regex.Replace(s0, @"^.*(a).*(c).*$", "$1$2");
Console.WriteLine(s1);
```

output:

```
ac
```

This questions reminds me of others I've seen where people wanted the regex to "skip" the parts of the string they weren't interested in--that is, to consume some parts but not others.  There's no way to do that in any of the regex flavors I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

```
var match = re.Match(s);
var captures = match.Groups["res"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value);
var result = string.Concat(captures);
```

The `Cast()` is necessary, because the collection that `Captures` returns doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.